# Js: proper way to change value of an input field

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change the value of a hidden input field.
The value i am trying to give it, came from a POST request to that particular route.

I am using js to inject the value to the hidden input field.

This is the code i am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var modelName = <%- JSON.stringify(data) %>; // get the data from routes.js
            document.getElementById("filePath").value = modelName; 
</script>
```

This script's location is inside the `<head>`.

However, the hidden input field's value does not change.
I do a `console.log()` in the route that the form performs a `POST`, and i see no value for this.
All the other parameters that this form posts to the route are rendered correctly.

Does it have to do with the fact that the js code is contained inside the `<head>`?
What is the correct way to perform this value injection?

Comment: why don't you put it directly where it needs to be ? you are using ejs right ?

Comment: @Noob yes, i am using ejs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably trying to set value of non-existing html element. Because you call this script in your head, html tag is not loaded yet. Try to put your script after end of body tag.

Let me know, if this works.

Comment: Thanks. But because, as you saw in the code, i posted, i am getting a value from the POST request, doesn't this code has to be on the <head>? I mean can i put the script after the HTML has loaded on the bottom of the page and keep that line inside? Or one script in the <head> where i get the value from the POST request, and one script at the end, where i inject that value on the input? And is this valid from a variable scope perspective?

Comment: This script should work as well on the bottom of the page. As I said, the problem is, that you are trying to set input of non existing html element.